# Why doesn't Hap have microphones in the basement?

Tags: the-oa

Hap has prisoners in his basement.

First, why doesn't he have microphones in the basement so he can listen to what his prisoners are saying? His prisoners are able to communicate with each other and plot their escapes/plans without him knowing what they're saying.

Second, why does he have monitors/screens for his prisoners showing them what's happening upstairs and even who's knocking on his front door? This allows his prisoners to plan and respond to events upstairs, which seems stupid.

Comment: How many microphones do you have in your house right now and do you already know how to set them up for 24x7 monitoring? How would you power them? How would you connect them? How would monitor their signals?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Do you have a lab and equipment in your house to repeatedly murder the same prisoners over many years and study these experiments? How would you do that?

Comment: I think that the problem with this question is that it accuses Hap (or the writers) of being darned if they do, darned if they don't. I mean the microphone part is a good question, considering he has all of that other tech, but I think going in the other direction just completely negates Haps intentions/the point of his role. When it gets down to it, outside of obvious plot conveniences, is that Hap is arrogant making him "Hap hazard". :p

Comment: @DarthLocke: *going in the other direction just completely negates Haps intentions/the point of his role* -- I'm not sure what you're referring to here

Comment: Well, having any equipment allows for him to be able to watch/record his subjects, which is why he has any equipment/certain kinds of tech at all, which is Hap's role - he's a villain scientist. So asking why he doesn't have a microphone makes sense, because that is fair question given everything else Hap has and what Hap's role in the story is. But not to have ANY negates from that role. He needs to be able to at least "watch" his subjects, even if there is a risk. Its just like you are trying to condem the writers for creating an imperfect character/plot

Comment: While Todd Wilcox's comments seem to indicate he hasn't seen the show, it still might be helpful to add context to your question by pointing out why Hap has equipment at all and/or what his/the story's situation is.

Comment: @DarthLocke: The Stackexchange family of websites is supposed to generate "expert" answers. I do not understand why persons such as Todd Wilcox who haven't at least watched the show (the very bare minimum requirement for being an "expert") try to answer or make comments here. Such low-quality comments and answers do not occur on most other SE sites I've been on. (Worse, in addition to not knowing anything about the show, he was highly snarky too.)

Comment: He was not answering the Q, he was making a comment to lightly "discuss" or make suggestions, even though I would agree that we all should aim to be friendlier. But questions still need to be well-formed and follow individualized SE site rules/formats in order to get better answers.